# How can I mock the following python function using MagicMock?

Tags: python, mocking, magicmock

```
class C:
  def f():
    calls g

  def g():
    # Do something
```

How can I mock g to test f in a testing module which imports class C?

Answer (score 0):

u can Mock that function with using path object like that;

```
with patch.object(C, 'g', MagicMock(return_value='something')):
    c.f()
```

with that way when your code calls g function, it returned mocked response

Note: use should import patch before use it

You can find detailed information from link below:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html